# Resizing a lot of images in parallel using a simple queuing system in Python and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, transactions, message-queue

I have a very large list of images that need to be re-sized, which stored in a MySQL database.

I have a few machines which I'd like to dedicated to the task of resizing the images:

```
- MySQL Database
- Worker node
- Worker node
- Worker node
- File server
```

I'm trying to create a program on each of the worker nodes that connects to the central MySQL server and grabs an image for re-sizing, and saves that image on the file server. When the re-sizing is complete, it would delete the the image from the re-sizing queue.

The problem I'm facing is: how do I deal with concurrency? If each of the worker nodes connects to the MySQL server at the same time, it's possible that they'll all pull the same record at once thus defeating the purpose of running these jobs in parallel. Is there a way to "lock" a row to ensure that each worker obtains a unique record?

What's a good strategy to do this? Or is there a better way all together?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a "work in progress" field to the images table. Bracket the process of SELECT and UPDATE one record in a BEGIN TRANSACTION and END TRANSACTION statement. Do work on the worker nodes in between.

Answer (score 0):

Never had the chance to face this problem. Would any of the following work?

- Have one process that pulls images from the queue, and send the job to an available worker.
- If the workers are equally efficient, use image id or some uniform hash to distribute the work load equally.
- Each worker pulls a random unprocessed image

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

1. Flag each record as they are taken in the DB by adding a field to the table that you can check/mark when one is starting.
2. Have each worker process a specific subset of records, perhaps mod the id or something.
3. If you are doing this often (or have other similar tasks) perhaps consider a message/task queue, for example RabbitMQ + Celery.